# How to dump data from SQL Server into MS Access table using hybrid connections

Tags: sql-server, vba, ms-access, ado, dao

I need to pull data from SQL server using a query where its statement is stored in a MS access table and dump the data into another table.

There are 2 tables, `01-MyStoredSQLs` and `02-tmpTableData`

The problem is that there are 2 connections as well. That's why I called it Hybrid.

My Final result is the data from SQL Server into the `tmpTableData` (result of a query where its statement is stored in the MyStoredSQLs table)

```vb
Public Sub DumpSQLServerData()
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
On Error GoTo errMSG

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection

conn.ConnectionString = "DSN=myDSN; UID=MyID;Pwd=MyPWd"
conn.Open

Dim db As DAO.Database
Set db = CurrentDb


Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
'Retrieving the SQL Statment that is stored in the MyStoredSQLs table
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT [Statement] FROM MyStoredSQLs WHERE ID=1")
Dim tmpSQL As String
Dim tmpINTOSQL As String


tmpSQL = rs(0)
'Hybrid statement 
tmpINTOSQL = "INSERT INTO tmpTableData" & tmpSQL

conn.Execute (tmpINTOSQL), dbFailOnError

conn.Close
rs.Close
db.Close

Set conn = Nothing
Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing
errMSG:
    Debug.Print Err.Description   
End Sub
```

Comment: "*using a query where its statement is stored in a MS access table"* That sounds really dangerous. If you are storing SQL statements to be run in an Access Database, I *hope* that they are very well validated before anyone inserts them.

Comment: In deed they are validated. The other option I have is using a .SQL file. But this will be necessary a different approach, I presume.

Comment: What's the problem? You haven't described any errors, if you use a linked table this should just work

Comment: I want to avoid linked tables. The error comes regarding the Object that doesn't exist on SQL Server database.
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]Invalid object name tmpTableData

Answer (score 0):

You can't expect SQL server to magically be able to access tables stored elsewhere.

Execute the query in Access, and either use a linked table, or specify the location of the table, e.g.

```
INSERT INTO tmpTableData SELECT Something FROM [ODBC;DSN=myDSN;UID=MyID;Pwd=MyPWd].Schema.TableInSQLServer
```

If you want to execute the query on SQL server, not Microsoft Access, then SQL server will need to be able to access the Access database file, and use `OPENROWSET` to query the Access table.

As an alternate, you can create a passthrough query, and use that to copy the table:

```
Dim qd As DAO.QueryDef
Set qd = db.CreateQueryDef("~tmpQuery")
qd.Connect = "ODBC;DSN=myDSN;UID=MyID;Pwd=MyPWd"
qd.ReturnsRecords = True
qd.SQL = tmpSQL
Set qd = Nothing
db.Execute "INSERT INTO tmpTable SELECT * FROM [~tmpQuery]"
db.QueryDefs.Delete "~tmpQuery"
```

Comment: The Query contains more than 01 table so I cannot use the ".TableInSQLServer". The SQL Statement has Where conditions, LEFT OUTER JOINS, etc. What is funny that I can do it easily in excel file, but not in MS Access tables.

Comment: Then you either need to prefix all tables with the location, or link tables. An alternate workaround would be to use a stored passthrough query, and then save the result of that passthrough query to a table.

Comment: @Luthius I edited in how to use a passthrough query

Comment: I guess you gave me an amazing clue. I will test and revert to you.